# Unable to transpile typescript to es5 when using AWS SDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, webpack, babeljs, k6

I'm running `k6`, which is a load testing tool built in `Go` that loads Javascript into a JS VM for execution. As such, I have some webpack and babel config that allows me to first transpile to es5 then the output bundle is what gets fed into the VM for execution.

The following is enough to reproduce the failure, which is that I cannot run anything imported from AWS.

```
Unexpected token (416:34)
  414 |   } = {}, viaHeader, payloadHash, expiresIn) {
  415 |     const credentials = await this.credentialProvider();
> 416 |     const region = signingRegion ?? (await this.regionProvider());
```

The above error is referring to the nullish operator. Additionally, I'm getting hit with this when underlying libs from AWS use things like the spread operator.

My Babel and Webpack files are at the bottom, but I specify transpilation to es5 and have the proper plugins added to resolve these issues, but the output bundle still has the code. What am I misunderstanding?

```js
import {
  S3Client,
  ListObjectsV2Command,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

import {
    getDefaultClientConfiguration,
    resolveDefaultRuntimeConfig
} from '@smithy/types/dist-es/extensions'

const S3 = new S3Client({
  region: "auto",
});
```

## Webpack

```
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const GlobEntries = require('webpack-glob-entries');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: GlobEntries('./src/**/*.ts'), // Generates multiple entry for each test
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules\/(?!aws-sdk|@aws-sdk|@smithy).*/,
      },
      {
        type: 'javascript/auto',
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: 'json-loader'
      },
    ],
  },
  target: 'node',
  externals: /^(k6|https?\:\/\/)(\/.*)?/,
  // Generate map files for compiled scripts
  devtool: "source-map",
  stats: {
    colors: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    // Copy assets to allow us to use and reference static content (ie test videos)
    // see `src/post-file-test.ts` for an test example using an asset
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [{ 
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'), 
        noErrorOnMissing: true 
      }],
    }),
  ],
  optimization: {
    // Don't minimize, as it's not used in the browser
    minimize: false,
  },
};
```

## Babel

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/env", "@babel/typescript"],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you check the official [k6 typescript template](https://github.com/grafana/k6-template-typescript)? What are the contents of your [`tsconfig.json`](https://github.com/grafana/k6-template-typescript) file? How are you running babel/webpack and packaging your files?